# How to automatically include back-references from references to citations

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

In this [publication](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/502.pdf) at the references for each citation there is a link to the document where the reference came from. I found it very useful. How this can be done in an automatic way?

Comment: You might want to check the other questions tagged with [tag:back-referencing].

Answer (score 8):

If you use Biblatex:

`\usepackage[..., backref=true]{biblatex}`

Answer (score 3):

`\usepackage[...,backref]{hyperref}`

Comment: I believe this doesn't work with `Biblatex`, though. I get an error message: "! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'backref'."

Comment: Please don't post one-line-of-code answers, even if they answer the question. Add at least some text.